# How to disregard checkpoints in Hyper-V?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, checkpoint

I start using Microsoft Hyper-V for testing before deployment to end-users and/or trouble-shooting. For this purpose, I have a rather fresh OS image of my employer, let's call the checkpoint `root`. If I mess this one up, I cannot easily recover it.

Now, for a complex test, I prepare the VM with pre-requisites and create a checkpoint `test-start`. I can revert to this, whenever I need to start a new run. So far everything is perfect.

The question: How can I simply disregard this `test-start` checkpoint without merging it into my `root`, once I finished the testing? If `test-start` would have child checkpoints, I would like to disregard them as well. In summary, I'd like to do `delete checkpoint subtree`, but without the merging that implicitly happens if doing so.

I have been searching quite a bit on the web, of course reading [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints) as well, but couldn't find that kind of information.  I hope this question is not too stup... ehm, trivial .. yet simple to answer for somebody.

Answer (score 3):

I believe by deleting the `test-start` checkpoint and discarding the changes you mean to restore the virtual machine to its original state, i.e. the `root` checkpoint. That's exactly what's needed to be done. Revert the virtual machine to the `root` checkpoint and delete the `test-start` subtree. By reverting to `root` checkpoint, the `test-start` and its subtree will belong to a point in time after the current running state, so the corresponding `AVHDX` files will be deleted immediately without merging.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out and used it as such since then. In the start I was only afraid it would merge upwards. It's very trivial once you know it, but scary the first time you try it ;).

Comment: @Dr.V I figured you already know the answer. I had the same question and a google search led me to this post, but I couldn't find a clear answer here and I had to do more research to figure out the answer, so I just wanted to post the answer here in case other people have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I found some [other MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn818483(v=ws.11)#deleting-a-checkpoint). It seems so simple that deleting a checkpoint in another branch or ahead in time of the currently running VM, the merging is not happening, and "deleting" the checkpoint actually is a pure "delete" operation.